# Events don't work laravel, in the queue, the process is in progress and gives an error

Tags: php, laravel

Created an event, it works locally, uploaded it to the server stopped working.

[2021-04-02 14:26:51] local.ERROR: Class 'Redis' not found {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class 'Redis' not found at /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php:75)
[stacktrace]

how to connect Redis?

PrivatMessageEvent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class PrivatMessageEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('private-channel');
    }
}
```

When I start the queue, I can see that this event is in progress but gives an Failed.

Script blade template

```
 socket.on("private-channel:App\\Events\\PrivatMessageEvent", function (message) {
                appendMessageToReceiver(message);
            });
```

config\bd

```
   'redis' => [
        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),
        'cluster' => false,
        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'database' => 0,
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify you've got the phpredis extension installed and enabled?

Please check the introduction section in the Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redis#introduction

Comment: my config bd.
   'redis' => [
        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),
        'cluster' => false,
        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'database' => 0,
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        ]
    ]

Comment: Thanks, but you'll require some additional dependencies to actually use the Redis implementation. Try running `pecl install redis` or `composer require predis/predis`.

Comment: @РомаЛытарь Check what you set `REDIS_CLIENT` to in your `.env`, too.

Comment: in .env REDIS_CLIENT there is nothing, what should be there?

Comment: composer require predis/predis done.
i check the status of the radish and it is active

Comment: database.php = 'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

Answer (score 0):

You should install redis package for the php version being used.
If your php version is 8.0 then

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-redis
```